# Do not see the java and maven configuration option in Jenkins configurations

Tags: maven, jenkins

Do not see the java and maven configuration option in Jenkins configurations. I would like to configure my maven

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to :

1. Download maven to some path on your computer
2. In the Jenkins dashboard (Home screen), click Manage Jenkins from the left-hand side menu.
3. Then, click on ‘Configure System’ from the right hand side.
4. In the Configure system screen, scroll down till you see the Maven section and then click on the ‘Add Maven’ button.
5. Uncheck the ‘Install automatically’ option.Add any name for the setting and the location of the MAVEN_HOME. Then, click on the ‘Save’ button at the end of the screen.
6. You can now create a job with the ‘Maven project’ option. In the Jenkins dashboard, click the New Item option.

[screenshot](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_maven_setup.htm)

Comment: I have installed maven. Do i need to add it in the same path as jenkins?

Comment: Jenkins provides excellent support for Maven, and has a good understanding of Maven project structures and dependencies. You can either get Jenkins to install a specific version of Maven automatically  ... or provide a path to a local Maven installation ... in Jenkins config

Comment: Maven Integration plugin, is bundled with Jenkins so search it and configure it , and you be able to build any maven project